# How to display RGB image in zerobrane studio?

Tags: lua, torch, luajit, zerobrane

On Ubuntu 14.04, if I run the following code within the qlua interpreter invoked via the command line (with or without the first line), it displays the Lena image :

```
require('mobdebug').start()    -- for image.display()
require 'image'
image.display( image.lena() )
```

and I can display a gray scale image via gnuplot:

```
require 'gnuplot'
require 'image'
M = image.rgb2y( image.lena() )
P = M[{1,{},{}}]
gnuplot.imagesc(P)
```

However, if I set the Zerobrane Studio v1.30 interpreter to QLua-LuaJIT (there is not a "qlua" interpreter)  via Project->LuaInterpreter and run it, I get this error:

```
Program 'qlua' started in '/opt/zbstudio/myprograms' (pid: 4608).
Debugging session started in '/opt/zbstudio/myprograms/'.
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
/home/dj/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/mobdebug.lua:1093: attempt to      call local 'report' (a string value)
stack traceback:
    [string "xpcall(function() io.stdout:setvbuf('no'); re..."]:1: in    function 'report'
    /home/dj/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/mobdebug.lua:1093: in function 'loop'
    [string "xpcall(function() io.stdout:setvbuf('no'); re..."]:1: in function <[string "xpcall(function() io.stdout:setvbuf('no'); re..."]:1>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    [string "xpcall(function() io.stdout:setvbuf('no'); re..."]:1: in  main chunk
    Debugging session completed (traced 4 instructions).
    Program completed in 4.12 seconds (pid: 4608).
```

How do I display an RGB image from within ZBS?

Comment: Before `Program 'qlua' started...` message, there should be `Program starting as...` message in the Output panel; does that command work when you execute it from the command line outside of ZeroBrane Studio?

Comment: Program starting as '"/home/dj/torch/install/bin/qlua" -e "xpcall(function() io.stdout:setvbuf('no'); require('mobdebug').loop('SignalProcessor',8172) end,function(err) print(debug.traceback(err)) end)"'.
    Program 'qlua' started in '/home/dj/Torch' (pid: 17629).

Comment: The first line with mobdebug locks up a Terminal window, but the following two lines work fine.
    `dj@SignalProcessor:~/Torch$ qlua
    Lua 5.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio`
`> require 'image'
> image.display(  image.lena() )
> -- the above two lines show the lena image`